# Can a kineticist voluntarily dismiss their kinetic covers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, duration, kineticist, occult-magic

[Kinetic Cover](https://www.aonprd.com/KineticistTalentsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kinetic%20Cover) allows the [kineticist](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kineticist) to create a small wall. Using the ability is a standard action. The ability description tells the maximum number of kinetic covers that can be created at once.

The power explains how kinetic covers can be destroyed, but specifies no duration or, as far as I can see, a way for the kineticist to dismiss the covers (without destroying them).

Is there a duration after which the covers lapse or a means to dismiss kinetic covers other than destroying or dispelling them?

Comment: After some research, I'm pretty sure there's no official answer for this. Is speculation based on precedent acceptable, or is official word necessary for a good answer?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Lack of official word (with some justification that it is not hiding anywhere reasonable) followed by precedents is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the [kineticist](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/occultAdventures/classes/kineticist.html) utility wild talent kinetic cover has no listed duration. This is unaddressed by the [*Occult Adventures* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1h5), mentioned as an issue once in the kineticist playtest thread from [2014](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rn8q&page=27?General-Discussion-Kineticist#1335) (and another user's followup post is of no help), and is unmentioned in class author Mark Seifter's ongoing [Ask Me Anything](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r7kg&page=1?Ask-Mark-Seifter-All-Your-Questions-Here) thread. This last would likely be the most direct way to get a semi-official answer as to the duration of kinetic cover until and if *Occult Adventures* receives errata.

## Probably *not* [instantaneous *nor* permanent yet dismissible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Duration)

Without a listed duration, kinetic cover is created instantaneously, remaining in place until destroyed. As the created wall is both paper thin with no hardness and pitiful hp *and* crumbles under 5 lbs. of weight, [most](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/toad) [creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/thrush) can destroy it with ease. This would be fine except that "you can have a number of kinetic covers in existence equal to your Constitution modifier + 1/2 your kineticist level," and if, for example, a kineticist uses all his kinetic covers in a dungeon and teleports away, the kineticist must *either* hope that dungeon denizens hate walls made of water or whatever and destroy them *or* return himself or send agents to the dungeon to destroy his own kinetic covers just so he can make more. That's silly.

Were kinetic covers permanent yet dismissible, they become vulnerable to *dispel magic* effects, but then the kineticist can take a standard action to dismiss a kinetic cover. However, the rules for dismissible effects still require the effect's controller to be "within range of the spell's effect," and the range of kinetic cover is only 30 ft. While *better* than instantaneous, this isn't *much* better.

#### Rounds equal to the kineticist's Constitution modifier? Sure, I guess

The powers cloud, wall, deadly earth, mobile blast, and others have this duration. It's long enough to matter in combat but not long enough to cripple the power were the kineticist instantaneously transported a vast distance from his kinetic covers. Extending the duration to longer rounds runs the risk of the previous covers' existence preventing the current use of *any* covers, and that would suck. In fact, were I playing a kineticist, I'd argue against the GM trying to impose a more typical duration like 1 min./level or 1 hour/level. A low-level kineticist needs to be able to use his powers, and there's a point when the kinetic cover talent can be a kineticists's *only* utility power.