# Can a Kineticist dismiss their own infusion-modified blasts with a standard action in the same way as dismissible spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

Some infusions add a duration to kineticist powers, such as the Wall or Cloud infusions, to name a few. My question is--can the Kineticist dismiss the infusion like a dismissible spell (standard action), or even as a free action? Or is it sitting there for the entire duration regardless?

Comment: I think [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91001/8610) may be closely related.

Comment: Perhaps related but not really an answer. As described in that question, 'kinetic covers' (and I don't even know what those are) has no listed duration. Kinetic powers like Wall do have a listed duration (# rounds = Con mod or til use the power again) but nowhere does it say whether Kineticist powers can be voluntarily dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

#### No

Like all abilities, kineticist class features that don't have clauses in their text allowing the kineticist to dismiss them (or inherit such clauses from a spell they emulate) can't be dismissed. You have to wait for their duration to end.